# How do defines and syntax macros interact in Racket?

Tags: macros, racket

I'm new to Racket and there's something about syntax macros I don't understand. I have these two programs:

This one, which executes correctly:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (create name) (define name 2))

(create x)

(displayln (+ x 3))
```

And this one, which complains that the identifier `x` is unbound:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (create) (define x 2))

(create)

(displayln (+ x 3))
```

With a naive substitution approach (such as C/C++ macros) these two programs would behave identically, but evidently they do not. It seems that identifiers that appear in the invocation of a syntax macro are somehow "special" and `define`s that use them behave differently to `define`s that do not. Additionally, there is the `struct` syntax macro in the Racket standard library which defines several variables that are not explicitly named in its invocation, for example:

```
(struct employee (first-name last-name))
```

Will define `employee?` and `employee-first-name`, neither of which were directly named in the invocation.

What is going on here, and it can be worked around so that I could create a custom version of `struct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the naive substitution is unintentional capturing. Racket macros by default are hygienic, which means it avoid this problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro for more details.

That being said, the macro system supports unhygienic macros too. `struct` is an example of an unhygienic macro. But you need to put a bit more effort to get unhygienic macros working.

For example, your second version of `create` could be written as follows:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax-parse-rule (create) 
  #:with x (datum->syntax this-syntax 'x)
  (define x 2))

(create)

(displayln (+ x 3))
```